# Three functions to select a random character, each of which can be used at most twice

Tags: python, random

I'm attempting to minimise the "duplicate" functions I have defined which do *almost* the exact same thing, but I'm unsure of the best way to do it, I thought of passing in the type I'm looking for (e.g. 1 for GreyLeader, 2 for HeadMarshal etc.) but that ended up looking too messy for my liking.

Could you guys perhaps suggest a way to combine the three functions into one to return the same result?

Some notes:
 - marshal is a list of a Marshal class which has Name, HeadMarshal, Marshal, GreyLeader boolean flags as properties
 - usedMarshals is a list of Marshals
 - each marshal can only be used twice, so the usedMarshals.count(marshal) = 2 is used for that

Code:

```
def get_marshal():
    marshal = random.choice(marshals)
    if marshal.Marshal:
        if not marshal in usedMarshals:
            return marshal
        elif marshal in usedMarshals:
            if usedMarshals.count(marshal) < 2:
                return marshal
            elif usedMarshals.count(marshal) >= 2:
                return get_marshal()
    elif not marshal.Marshal:
        return get_marshal()


def get_head_marshal():
    marshal = random.choice(marshals)
    if marshal.HeadMarshal:
        if not marshal in usedMarshals:
            return marshal
        elif marshal in usedMarshals:
            if usedMarshals.count(marshal) < 2:
                return marshal
            elif usedMarshals.count(marshal) >= 2:
                return get_head_marshal()
    elif not marshal.HeadMarshal:
        return get_head_marshal()


def get_grey_leader():
    marshal = random.choice(marshals)
    if marshal.GreyLeader:
        if not marshal in usedMarshals:
            return marshal
        elif marshal in usedMarshals:
            if usedMarshals.count(marshal) < 2:
                return marshal
            elif usedMarshals.count(marshal) >= 2:
                return get_grey_leader()
    elif not marshal.GreyLeader:
        return get_grey_leader()
```

Comment: Maybe `get_leader(kind): leader = random.choice( (m for m in marshals if isinstance(m, kind) ) )` I cannot test it without the marshal classes. Where kind is `marshal.Marshal` or `marshal.HeadMarshal` or `marshal.GreyLeader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Iterative instead of recursive

   Python doesn't really suit itself for recursion

   - No tail recursion
   - Generally slower
   - Limited max depth
2. Use `ALL_CAPS` for *constant* variables

   `marshels` is a constant variable and should be written in `ALL CAPS`

   Thnx @Gareth Rees for clarifying
3. Functions and variables should be `snake_case`
4. @Caridorc is correct in saying that something like `isinstance()` might work, but without the actual class it is difficult to tell
5. Think about changing the data type of `usedMarshels`

   `list.count(x)` is an \$O(n)\$ operation, [see time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), meaning it will have to loop through the entire list to find how many there are.

   Instead you could hold a dictionary of the amount of marshals making it an \$O(1)\$ operation.

*Here is some code to give you an idea hopefully,*

```
import random

# Random Marshall class
class Marshel():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

a = Marshel("First Marshal")
b = Marshel("Second Marshal")

MARSHELS = [a, b]        
used_marshals = {a: 2, b: 1}

def get_leader(type_):
    while True:
        # marshal = random.choice((m for m in MARSHELS if isinstance(m, type_)))
        marshal = random.choice(MARSHELS)
        if marshal not in used_marshals or used_marshals[marshal] < 2:
            return marshal

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_leader("Does nothing yet"))
    # Will print "Second Marshal" because that is the only viable option
```

Comment: According to PEP8, `ALL_CAPS` is only for [*constants*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants); global *variables* should be [named like functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names), that is, in `snake_case`.

Comment: Thanks! With the isinstancetype(),  if the Marhsel class had a property of 'type' as well as its 'name', and wanted to determine if its type was 1, would I then have three different classes and use them like 'Marshel(type_1)' and then isinstancetype(marshal, type_1) to determine if its type one? Or can I do something easier?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
def get_something(marshal_etc):
    marshal = random.choice(marshals)
    if marshal.marshal_etc:
        if not marshal in usedMarshals:
            return marshal
        elif marshal in usedMarshals:
            if usedMarshals.count(marshal) < 2:
                return marshal
            elif usedMarshals.count(marshal) >= 2:
                return get_something()
    elif not marshal.marshal_etc:
        return get_something()
```

You could just make a generic function that takes an input of all your options, you can do this by replacing any occurrence of those options with a generic label `marshal_etc` or whatever you like.

Then just run `get_something(HeadMarshal)` or `get_something(Marshal)` or `get_something(GrayLeader)` as needed